# My Google Maps API Maps Not Working - Showing White

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've been generating some Google Maps using the Maps API for many months now and all has been fine. Suddenly they've stopped working and I have no idea why.

Here's a simple map that was previously working fine:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">

var map = null;
function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
zoom: 12,
scaleControl: true,center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.7317470,151.0791569),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 }
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
 myOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
infowindow.close();
});

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.0113130,151.5838010);
var icon = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
var marker = createMarker(point,'<p style="font-size:14px">John Smith<br>123 Smith St, Sydney<br>Distance away: 92.7 km<br> Phone H: <a href="sip:02 1234 5678">02 1234 5678</a><br> Phone M: <a href="sip:0412 345 678">0412 345 678</a><br>Acme Inc</p>', icon)

}
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{ 
size: new google.maps.Size(100,20)
});
function createMarker(latlng, html, icon) {
var contentString = html;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng,
icon: icon,
map: map,
zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
 infowindow.setContent(contentString);
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now for some reason I'm not able to see the map - I get a blank white web browser page. Can anyone spot an error or has the Maps API changed recently - I haven't had to generate a map for a few weeks which was the last time I tried and it was working fine.

Comment: Try setting `height` for your `#map_canvas`.

Comment: No it does not. The CSS included sets a height for `#map-canvas`. OP's map is called `#map_canvas`. So either renaming the elements id or adding `height`.